# Couchbase java-client IllegalReferenceCountException

Tags: java, couchbase

I was getting this error on `java-client-2.1.0` while trying to work with `AsyncBucket`:

```
com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
```

After a while I figured it out. Couchbase completely ignores this scenario so there's no proper feedback from the library and the Netty internals aren't helping.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you'll get that error when consuming CB's items more than once. For example,

```
val getObs = asyncBucket.get("blah")
val emptyObs = getObs.isEmpty.doOnEach(...).subscribe()
val docObs = getObs.doOnEach(...).subscribe()
```

That is the only way I could come up with to handle a "document not found" scenario.

To work around this, use `cache()`:

```
val getObs = asyncBucket.get("blah").cache()
```

The caching observer will consume the Couchbase's item and then the multiple subscribers can safely consume from the cache.

If you're using `rxscala`, the fix is the same.

```
getObs.singleOption.foreach { ... }
```

Would fail without the cache.